# I am trying to draw shapes in flutter in the top right and bottom left of the screen but I couldn't do exactly the same

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, mobile, shapes

How could I achieve these 3 shapes in flutter?

excuse my drawing! :)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md2AX.jpg)

Comment: use custom painter

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: -50,
            top: -100,
            child: Container(
              width: 400.0,
              height: 400.0,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: -50,
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
            child: Container(
              width: 200.0,
              height: 200.0,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: -50,
            bottom: -100,
            child: Container(
              width: 400.0,
              height: 400.0,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: if it worked well, please mark as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you have the SVG code of the any shape [SVG to Code](https://www.flutterclutter.dev/tools/svg-to-flutter-path-converter/) then you can just copy paste the code, as custonPaint code which is the best to way to do this I think